# Multipass VM (macOS host) -> mount failed: source "<path_to_dir>" is not readable

Tags: macos, multipass

## Problem

New install of Multipass VM (https://multipass.run/) on macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

```
$ multipass mount <path_to_host_dir> <vm name>:<path_to_vm_dir>

> mount failed: source "<path_to_dir>" is not readable
```

## Solution

Full access needs to be granted to Multipass via the macOS system preferences.

```
System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Full access needs to be granted to Multipass via the macOS system preferences.

```
System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy
```